# numbering page in crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, page-numbering

am using crystal report in C# asp.net ..

i need help on this :
and am trying to make my report start from number 5 NOT 1
i tried to write PageNumber=5; like this :

```
in footer group -> section expert -> reset page number after -> formal Editor -> PageNumber=5;
```

its reset after page 5 .. i want it from beginning start from a number i give ..

also i try it on new page before and i add it there it not work 
what should i do ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't go to `reset page number` instead create a formula and write below code and place place in page footer.

Create formula `@Page Number`

```
pagenumber+4
```

Now place above formula in `page footer`